# AWS Lambda: using CloudwatchEvent.disableRule() doesn't work within Lambda but works in local

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to disable the Cloudwatch Event Rule that is triggering a Lambda, within the Lambda itself, so that it doesn't keep running when it's not necessary to do so.

I have a separate Lambda that is calling enableRule to enable the rule, which seems to work fine. The rule is not associated with the function that is doing enableRule. EDIT: Turns out the EnableRule doesn't work in Lambda either.

However, this Lambda that's supposed to disable it isn't working.

Both functions already have Cloudwatch and CloudwatchEvent Full Access rights in their roles.

```
var cloudwatchEvents = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents();

var params = {
   Name: cloudwatchEventRuleName
}
console.log("this message will show up");
cloudwatchEvents.disableRule(params, function (err, data) {
   console.log("but this message never appears when it runs via Lambda for some reason!")
   if (err)
      console.log(err,err.stack);
   else
      console.log(data);
});
console.log("and this message will also show up");
```

That line where it was supposed to call the middle console.log doesn't work at all if I run it through Lambda. It's working perfectly in my local, however.

I even printed the cloudwatchEventRuleName to check if I have any typos, but the function name seems right. It's like the function is just outright skipping the disableRule function altogether for whatever reason.

Comment: You should do a try-catch instead of console.log. Do you have error logs for this execution ? Is your IAM properly configured for that ? Maybe if your Lambda doesn't have the permission, then the function fails immediately.

Comment: "Both functions already have Cloudwatch and CloudwatchEvent Full Access rights in their roles."

I actually kind of wish it was just permissions, since at least an error would have come up.

Even if I do a try-catch there wasn't anything different. It's like it just skips over the entire command for whatever reason. The console.log was the example given in the AWS JS SDK documentation, and I did pass erroneous parameters to it and it returned me an error (local run), so I know that at least I can trace it with that. It's just specifically when it runs in Lambda where it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, years later, setting up VPCs still haunt me.

Yep, it's a VPC configuration thing.

I could swear that the Subnet that the Lambda function was using had a route table that pointed to a properly set up Network Interface with a NAT Gateway Instance.

Out of curiosity, I tried making the route table entry of 0.0.0.0/0 point to the instance (i-#####) rather than the network interface (eni-######).

After I pressed Save in the Route Table, it automatically transformed into eni-######, similar to what I already had it set up...

**Except this time the function actually started working now.**

I have no idea what kind of magic AWS did so that associating an instance =/= associating to a network interface even though the former transformed into the same ID anyway, but whatever.

So for anyone encountering this same problem: **always remember to double-check if your function actually has access to the internet to use the AWS APIs**.

EDIT: Also another thing: I had to make sure that enableRule and disableRule were both awaited, as for some reason the AWS requests can in fact not be sent properly if the handler already returned something before the request was completed. So we turned into a promise just so we can await it:

```
try { await cloudwatchEvents.disableRule(params).promise().then((result) => console.log(result)) }
catch (error) { console.log("Error when disabling rule!", error); }
```